# building bitcoin core - how to temporarily disable WSL support for Win32 applications

Tags: bitcoind, windows, wsl

The build-windows.md says:
"Additional WSL Note: WSL support for [launching Win32 applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wsl/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability#launching-win32-applications-from-within-wsl)
results in `Autoconf` configure scripts being able to execute Windows Portable Executable files. This can cause
unexpected behaviour during the build, such as Win32 error dialogs for missing libraries. The recommended approach
is to temporarily disable WSL support for Win32 applications."

How should I temporarily disable it? Is it done in the Ubuntu WSL shell, or in my local Windows machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable WSL support for Win32 applications:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 0 > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status"
```

Enable WSL support for Win32 applications:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/status"
```

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-windows.md#building-for-64-bit-windows

> Is it done in the Ubuntu WSL shell, or in my local Windows machine?

Ubuntu WSL shell

Comment: Right. The title says "Build using:" and I expected the command to be before that, so I missed the comment in the script. Thanks.